# Game mods: when should I use a hook over patching memory?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, hook

I have been learning how to make game mods, and I've gotten to the stage where I've made external and internal trainers successfully and the next step is learning how to use hooks.

So far I have been using

```
ReadProcessMemory / WriteProcessMemory
```

and internally writing to addressess like this

```
uintptr_t ammoAddr = mem::FindDMAAddy(moduleBase + 0x10F4F4, { 0x374, 0x14, 0x0 });
int* ammo = (int*)ammoAddr;
*ammo = 1337;

or

*(int*)mem::FindDMAAddy(moduleBase + 0x10F4F4, { 0x374, 0x14, 0x0 }) = 1337;
```

I've used these to simply get entity health and positions, so just using their values. Is it worthwhile making a hook for these? At the moment I only see a purpose in hooking DirectX and things like that.

I'm going to assume that these might be hooks, and if not what are they? What are the point of different hooks, as in why would I use a trampoline hook in order to get the value of a memory adress?  Is it simply for detection purposes or are these quicker/more efficient?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this, but aren't hooks for functions? Not for variables, which health and positions are.

Comment: Yes but the way I've seen hooks being used is you hook into a function in order to write/store the variable.  Correct me if im wrong but im not too sure. For example the function for taking damage is, health -1, and you'd change the variable health from within the function. But thats my question really, why hook a function to change the health when I can write to it directly like mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume some simplified game code like this exists:

```
void Player::takeDamage(int dmg) {
  this->health -= dmg;
  if (this->health <= 0)
    youDied();
}
```

Constantly writing "100" to the address of `Player::health` means "racing" the game code to make sure the check never fires. Moreover, the compiler might decide to restructure the code as follows:

```
void Player::takeDamage(int dmg) {
  int newHealth = this->health - dmg;
  this->health = newHealth;
  if (newHealth <= 0)
    youDied();
}
```

In both cases, no matter how often you write to `Player::health`, the `youDied` case can still trigger.

In contrast, if you hook `Player::takeDamage` and decide  not to execute the method body, the player is effectively immune to damage.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me understand the reason behind hooking and when to use it. Appreciate it!